# automatically set random featured image by category in wordpress on post

Tags: plugins, posts, categories, post-thumbnails

Basically I want to automatically set an image randomly from a selection of about 3 or 4 images in my Media Library when someone posts a blog from a particular category. 
I've got this so far but it only sets one image for that category.

```
function default_category_featured_image() {
global $post;
$featured_image_exists = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);

if (!$featured_image_exists)  {
$attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );

if ($attached_image) {

foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment);
}}
else if ( in_category('49') ) {
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '2200');
    wp_reset_postdata();
}                      
                           }

      }
add_action('the_post', 'default_category_featured_image');
```

Is it possible to have more than one feature image randomly for each category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prepare an [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) of images ids for each category and pick one of them randomly. I say "one of them" since the featured image is always 1 if I understood well your question.. which is somehow ambiguous when you say *set an image* and later *to have more than one feature image*
So, editing part of your code and assuming that the rest is working:

```
//...
else if ( in_category('49') ) {
  // array of  ids of images for this category
  $arrImages = array(2200,2201,2202);

  // get random index from array $arrImages
  $randIndex = array_rand($arrImages);

  // output the value for the random index
  set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $arrImages[$randIndex]);
  //wp_reset_postdata();

}
else if ( in_category('50') ) { // for example.. and so on
  $arrImages = array(2203,2204,2205);
  $randIndex = array_rand($arrImages);
  set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $arrImages[$randIndex]);
}
```

`wp_reset_postdata();` is not actually needed since you're not altering the main query see [wp_reset_postdata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/)